# Entropy of a character in a String

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Taking into account the *Shannon entropy*, I was wondering that, if we have a String like $1122344444455$ , is this possible to find out the entropy of digit $4$ in this String? In other words, I would like to know if we can find a way to measure the degree of uncertainty of occurrence of digit $4$ in this String. Is this the responsibility of *Relative entropy*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entropy is a measure of how much information there is in one source with one probability distribution. Relative entropy is a measure how close or distant one probability distribution is to another. If you have one probability distribution you wish to test against your string then you could calculate a relative entropy.

Entropy can be defined as $$E(k) = \sum_{\forall i} -p_i\log_k(p_i)$$, which is the expected value of the logarithm of the probabilities. What is interesting here is that each $p_i$ occurs only in one term of this sum. So each outcome contributes with an own addition to the entropy.

It seems I need to clarify some words. If we consider (1,2,3,4,5) to be the "alphabet" ( in language of probability : the set of possible outcomes ). Each element (like "4") can be called a "symbol". Using these words instead of probability words are common to do in information theory. Which could be one of the tags the bot wanted us to add to the question.

The entropy of "4" is the expected number of bits on average we would need to store "4". 6 out of 13 symbols are "4". Let us for simplicity guess that 6 out of 12 or 7 out of 14 are "4". Then 4 would occur almost half of the symbols. The entropy (in binary digits) would then be $-\frac{1}{2} \log_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$ which means that on average we would need 1/2 bits per symbol to consider if it was a "4" or not.

Having an entropy of 1/2 means that if "4" occurs on average 1 in 2 symbols we should need on average 1/2 bit per symbol to tell if it was a 4.

---

The thing with [Relative Entropy or Kullback-Leibler Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is that it requires **two** distributions, we got to have some second distribution to compare against. Once we have that it's just to follow the formula on the wikipedia page. It's very straight forward.

Comment: What do you mean half bits per symbol? what is the symbol in here? the whole stream of digits?

Comment: I would also like to point out that in here, these digits are a symbol of a system response. Consider there is a **relevancy feedback** system that returns an answer to a query. So my aim is to show that how unexpected are the results of this system. In other words, the system should make as diverse response as possible to the **different** queries. So if we get the idea that this system is giving quite similar answers for different queries, then we conclude this system might has a low throughput. As a result, my question here is that if I am using right way of using entropy here?

Comment: Yes relative entropy could be a useful measure for how unexpected or deviating something is in the strings.

Comment: Alright, then why did you not explain anything about how to compute the relative entropy of 4 in this String? Because I have a little bit of hard time getting it into my head. After reading your edited answer, I got some more clues of entropy but what about the relative one? Can you also explain it with the digit 4 in here?

Comment: Because relative entropy needs two distributions and we only have one.

Comment: Alright. So the result for 4, which is 1/2, means that the digit 4 is so expected? right? Can you tell me a boundary of values of entropy for this matter?

Comment: If there was a boundary to the entropy of a single symbol then it would be an extremum to the function $-p_i\log_k(p_i)$ but that is a different although important calculus question. Also the function E(k) in it is also possible to find bounds for as it is a concave function which are very nice to do mathematical optimization on (compared to if it was not).

Comment: So, how can i tell if a symbol is highly uncertain or not by the value of entropy?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, for any set of String, like what I mentioned in my question before gets edited, there must be a max entropy and min entropy. How can I know what is this max and min?

Comment: The minimum entropy is always 0. That is when one particular symbol occurs all the time (100% probability) and all other symbols occur with 0 probability. For instance if the string could only contain "4"s, then entropy would be 0. The maximum entropy is for the uniform distribution, where each symbol has the same probability.

Comment: That means i should calculate the uniform distribution and compare it with the entropy I obtained?

Comment: Why don't you read a bit on wikipedia or an introduction to probability theory and information theory. Most of what you are asking is there.

Comment: I already read there but cannot find these in wikipedia. Sorry for disturbing you.